# binding dynamic HTML select element in angular with dropzone.js

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js, which **dynamically adds HTML** content to a page when a file is dropped.

In my case the dynamic HTML contains an **angular** bound `select` element.

I need angular to refresh (and bind) the select contained in the dynamic HTML.

I am attempting to use the `$compile` method to compile the added dom elements after they are added by dropzone, so that the `select` is populated.

```
// this directive creates the dropzone.js component, and attempts to
// compile the added dynamic HTML
export class DocumentDropZone implements ng.IDirective {
  constructor(public $log, public $compile) {
  }

  public link: Function = (scope: any, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => {
    this.$log.log('initialised drop zone.');
    var compile = this.$compile;
    var dz = new Dropzone("body",
        {
            url: 'test',
            previewTemplate: <any>$('script[type="text/template"]').html(),
            autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
            previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
            clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
            init: function() {
                  this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                  });

                  this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                      // ATTEMPT TO COMPILE THE ADDED DOM ELEMENT
                      // SO THAT ANGULAR BINDS THE SELECT
                      compile($('div#template'));
                  });

                  this.on('drop', function(file) {
                  });

                }
            });
  }
}
```

Here is a part of the template.

```
<select class="form-control"             
        ng-model="documentType"
        ng-options="documentType.name for documentType in dc.documentTypes track by documentType.id">
</select>
```

I **know the select works,** when not dynamically added as if I put the select somewhere else on the page it is populated correctly.

*The compile method doesn't seem to bind the select?*

I have also tried.

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    compile($('div#template'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who has this problem.
`$compile(element: HTMLElement)` returns a function.

The correct usage of `$compile` is.

```
compile($('div#template'))(scope);
```

Which correctly binds the created HTML to the controller scope.